# Using delegates to avoid subclassing

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates

I would like to have your opinion as to the pros and cons of using delegates instead of virtual functions aud subclassing?

Comment: That's not nearly enough information for us to come up with a useful answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the delegate issue is a red herring: this is really about the **[strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_Pattern)** versus the **[template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_Pattern)**.

["Favor composition over inheritance"](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/designprinciples4.html) is excellent advice, so the strategy pattern is the better default technique (whether you use objects or delegates to do your dirty work), mainly because it provides superior decoupling.

I only use subclassing (the template pattern) when there's a suitable inheritance relationship (per the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), the algorithm I'm varying needs access to the protected methods of the base class and I want a high degree of cohesion.

Answer (score 1):

It very muych depends whether you're aiming for the object oriented or functional style really.

- Object oriented => inheritance and overriding of methods
- Functional => passing delegates to method

Usually it's best to pick one or the other, but sometimes it doesn't hurt to mix. I generally try to stick to the OO approach, since that is the main heritage of C#.

However, in certain circumstances, passing lambda epxressions to functions removes a lot of the boilerplate code. Indeed, in the extreme case, the alternative to creating a method that takes a delegate/lambda expression could be overriding the base class a dozen or so times with minor changes. Saying this, if the behaviour you want to customise is fairly *fixed*, than subclassing is usually the better choice.

Comment: Could delegate also aid testing perhaps, since it won't be necessary to extract an interface or subclass to isolate a method ?

Comment: @Andrei: Yes, it could quite possibly make testing more straightforward, though I wouldn't base your design decision on it... Very much depends on the context - you usually don't want to be creating new derived classes for testing though.

Answer (score 1):

Vague question, so you get a vague answer:

Use virtual methods and subclassing to *represent a model*.  Use delegates to *implement a mechanism*.

See my answer to

[When to use callbacks instead of events in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020381/when-to-use-callbacks-instead-of-events-in-c)

for additional thoughts in this vein.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take.

1. Its not object oriented programming anymore. It's the old way of doing things.

Hm. That's all I have.

Comment: New does not necessarily mean better. Just sayin'