# How can I update the class without setInterval when comparing if-else statement for classList.contains?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need a solution for if-else comparing the `classList.contains` in JavaScript.
when I compare without `setInterval` the classList not working but I need a solution without `setInterval` because it's updating everything I need only to work the `classList.contains` when `onclick`. please see the code below.

```js
let ctx = document.querySelector('.control');
ctx.onclick = () => {
  box.classList.toggle('rds');
  document.onclick = null; // important idea
  box.classList.remove('ok')

}

setInterval(() => {
  if (box.classList.contains('rds')) {
    document.onclick = () => {
      box.classList.remove('rds');
      box.classList.add('ok')
    }
  } else {
    document.onclick = null; // important idea
  }
}, 1)
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  transition: 1s;
}

.rds {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ok {
  border: 10px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<button class="control">Control here</button>

<div class="box" id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Remove the intervall totally, and implement the logic in the ctx clickhandler function.

Comment: not working man, can you give me snippet?

Comment: actually the class not updating without setInterval but tried document.onmousemove = (){ /* structure */ } working, let me know if you have any idea

Answer (score 0):

I understood you. But you should also provide behavior of yours animation.
I did 2 variants without setInterval please check. And if it is okay for you, mark answer like correct.

jsfiddle 1:
https://jsfiddle.net/shuts13/dvp4tea9/21/

jsfiddle 2:
https://jsfiddle.net/shuts13/0emocq7j/1/

```
<button class="control" onclick="update()">Control here</button>

    <div class="box" id="box">

    </div>


    function update() {
  const box = document.getElementById('box');

              box.classList.add('rds');
              box.classList.add('ok');

  setTimeout(()=> {
            if(box.classList.contains('rds')){
                            console.log('ECIS')
                box.classList.remove('rds');
            } 
  }, 1000)
  }
```

Comment: not actually which I wanted, I need document and box onclick and without setInterval or setTimeout just remove setInterval from my js code and see, it will not work to document onclick but I need to work document onclick without setInterval or setTimeout , actually the box class not updating after adding new class but I need to update without setInterval

Comment: @NIKHILCHANDRAROY What behavior do you expect when document detects it has been clicked? All I see is that it does absolutely nothing (`null` to be precise).

Comment: but what do you want to do, I can't understand

Comment: click control here button than click document it will add ok class and remove rds class in box class

Comment: I need this behavior without setInterval

Comment: okay:  `function update() {
  const box = document.getElementById('box');
              box.classList.add('ok');
       box.classList.remove('rds');
  }` - function adds 'ok' class and remove 'rds' class, as you want, but you dont have rds class in html

Comment: one more: `  let ctx = document.querySelector('.control');
  ctx.onclick = () => {
    box.classList.remove('rds');
    box.classList.add('ok')

  }`

Comment: WARNING: you should add the Script at the bottom of body when DOM is loaded

Comment: when button will click the rds class will add and than document will behave, I had used the script at bottom

Answer (score 0):

## Problems

The **OP** <sup>1</sup> (aka **O**riginal **P**oster -- aka [@NIKHIL CHANDRA ROY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59822388/2813224)) use (*misuse?...abuse?*) of `setInterval()` is just a means to switch the *"state"* (**ex.** `.ok` and `.rds`) of `.box` I assume.

Concerning OP's misconceptions about (or perhaps failure to properly explain) the following statement:

```
document.onclick = null; // important idea
```

From what I gather is that OP is worried that `document` will detect the click event and call the event handler, thereby incurring two calls to the event handler in rapid succession. Once by `document` and the other by `.control` -- hence the misunderstanding that `setInterval()` was useful in this particular situation.

---

### [Event Handlers / Callbacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) <sup>2</sup>

OP treats the event handlers as normal anonymous functions (which is why OP is creating two separate functions to change two separate "states" and struggling with *when a call happens and when a call shouldn't*).

- **Standard Anonymous Function**
  Anonymous functions are defined and invoked when parsed. When the browser notices the parenthesis (**ex.** `function()`) it will interpret it as: *"Run this function **NOW**"*).

  ```
  const nodeRef = () => {... 
  /* or */  
  var nodeRef = function() {...
  ```
- **Event Handler**
   Event handlers are functions that ***wait for a registered event to happen before they run***. Note the similarities they share:

  ```
  //~~~~ Defined (aka Named)
  domNode.onclick = functionName; 
  /* or */ 
  domNode.addEventListener('click', functionName);

  function functionName(eventObject) {...

  /*~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~*/

  //~~~ Anonymous
  domNode.onclick = function(eventObject) {... 
  /* or */ 
  domNode.addEventListener('click', function(eventObject) {...
  ```

  - When registered event is triggered the event handler is called, thus the only time parenthesis are included is when an event handler is defined. Note a defined event handler does not have parenthesis `()` because their definitions are hoisted to the top.
  - Also by default event handlers pass the [**Event Object**](https://javascript.info/introduction-browser-events#event-object). Always include it as the first parameter when defining an event handler. By explicitly passing the event object (typically as `e`, `event`, `evt`...) the event handler can access the event object's properties such as [`event.type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/type), `event.currentTarget`, and `event.target`.
  - [**`event.currentTarget`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) is an object (typically a [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)) that is registered to an event (it *"listens"* for a specific event to happen). It is also referred to as `this` within the definition of its associated event handler.
  - [**`event.target`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) is the object to which the registered event originated from. For example, if the fifth button out of a hundred identical buttons was clicked, `event.target` will accurately reference that particular button.

Hopefully what an event handler is and what it does is a little more clearer. Moreover how indispensable Event Object is. The next section explains Event Phases which details the unseen chain of events happening within the [DOM tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Using_the_W3C_DOM_Level_1_Core).

---

### [Event Phases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture)

```
<!DOCTYPE html><!--document-------------------->
<html><!-----------document.documentElement---->
 ...
   <body><!--------document.body--------------->
     <form id="ui"><!--document.forms.ui-----➕--HTMLFormElement Interface
                    ---event.currentTarget---➕--Registered to click event
                    ---this-------------------->
       <button class='ctx'><!--event.target--⏬-->
         CLICKED!
       </button>
       <fieldset class='box ok'><!--event.target.nextElementSibling---❙--->
       </fieldset>
     </form>
    </body>
 </html>
```

#### Capture Phase

- **ex.** *User clicks `button.ctx` and becomes `event.target`*

  - `event.target` parent is `event.currentTarget` (ie `form`)
  - Event path: `document`, `html`, `body`, `form`.
  - The path (and current capture phase) ends when the parent of the event origin (aka `event.target`) has been reached.
  - This phase is rarely used specifically by the developer and is usually disregarded (there some exceptions such as key events)

#### Target Phase

- **ex.** *After completing the path from `document` to the parent element (ie `document.forms.ui`) of the `button` the target phase begins*

  - Once `event.target` is determined, the element positioned immediately after it (ie `event.target.nextElementSibling`) will change *"state"* (`.box.ok` OR `.box.rd`).
  - The event handler stops propagation (ie stops the bubbling phase from continuing) when target phase is completed or `.ctx` wasn't clicked. This desired behavior is done by ending statement: `event.stopPropagation()`.
  - Event path has only a single reference to `event.target`.
  - This phase is the most important one because it singles out the clicked button even if there were a thousand buttons.

#### Bubbling Phase

- **ex.** *Normally, after the target phase is complete the path is reversed.*

  - Since there where no other objectives it's pointless to continue the event chain so `event.stopPropagation()` prevents the click event from going any further up the DOM tree.
  - Incidentally, this also excludes ancestor elements / objects such as `document` from the click event.

---

Consider the programming pattern called [**Event Delegation**](https://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm).

- **Advantages**

  - Multiple ***targeted elements*** <sup>3</sup> (aka `event.target`) -- **ex.** a `<button>` user has clicked) can be specified and exclude ***non-targeted elements*** <sup>4</sup> (**ex.** `document` or `body` which could interfere and inhibit proper behavior if a click anywhere triggered an event handler).
  - Only register ***one element*** to handle ***one or more*** targeted elements at once.
  - The targeted elements include ones that are dynamically added in the future as well.
- **Requirements**

  - An ancestor element that all ***te*** have in common. It can be a top-level object such as `document` or `window` but it's better to assign or create an element that is as close to the ***te*** as possible. The closer the less likely  buggy behavior will occur (such as double calls to event handlers).
  - Register the event to said ancestor element. There are three ways to register an element to an event using plain JavaScript.

    - **On-event Property Event**
      My personal favorite because it's terse

      ```
      document.forms.ui.onclick = ctrl;
      ```
    - **EventListener**
      In general the most recommended way -- the only significant difference between them is that the third optional parameter will use the capture phase instead of the default bubbling phase by passing `true`.

      ```
      document.forms.ui.addEventListener('click', ctrl, true);
      ```
    - **On-event Attribute Event**
      This way of event handling is as old as dirt and its use is not recommended due to it's many limitations. I have included it just the sake of completeness, **DO NOT IMPLEMENT THIS TECHNIQUE**.

      ```
      <form id='ui' onclick="ctrl(e); return false">
        <button class='ctx' type='button'>THIS IS LAME!</button>
        <fieldset class='box ok'></fieldset>
      </form>
      ```
  - When defining the event handler, establish the following:

    - Ensure that the current `event.target` (remember the event phases are not idle) isn't `event.currentTarget`. Once that's establish narrow down the possibilities further by using control or ternary statements.

      ```
        ...
        if (event.target !== this) {
          if (event.target.classList.contains('ctx')) {...
        ...
      ```
    - By implementing narrow criterion and using `event.stopPropagation()`, excluding everything else is simple.

      ```
          ...
          } else {
            event.stopPropagation();
          }
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      ```

---

#### Demo

```js
const ui = document.forms.ui;

ui.onclick = ctrl;

function ctrl(event) {
  const clicked = event.target;

  if (clicked !== this) {
    if (clicked.classList.contains('ctx')) {
      const box = clicked.nextElementSibling;
      box.classList.toggle('ok');
      box.classList.toggle('rd');
    } else {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
.ctx {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border: 0;
  transition: 1s;
}

.rd {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.ok {
  border: 10px dotted blue;
}
```

```html
<form id='ui'>
  <button class="ctx" type='button'>Control</button>
  <fieldset class="box ok"></fieldset>
</form>
```

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> In the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com) community (not sure about the [SE](https://stackexchange.com/) as a whole), OP is used interchangeably between **O**riginal **P**oster (the member asking the question) or **O**riginal **P**ost (the question itself).

<sup>2</sup> At times the terms *event handler*, *event listener*, and *callback* may be used to refer to a function called after an event happens. For the purpose of this answer that holds true. For a more definitive explanation refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2069763/2813224).

<sup>3</sup> The term *targeted elements* (***te***)is coined by myself to refer to elements within the DOM that share a common ancestor and can be a potential `event.target` made possible by well crafted HTML/CSS and JavaScript configured to effectively delegate events.

<sup>4</sup> *Non-targeted elements* (***nte***) is an ad-hoc term to describe elements that should be excluded from reacting to certain events for various reasons. Commonly ***nte*** are the ancestor elements/objects of the `event.currentTarget` such as `document`, `body`, etc. While there are times when high level nodes on the DOM tree serve well as `event.currentTarget`, it's best to keep `event.currentTarget` as close to the ***te*** as possible.

---

#### References

The following references cover other aspects I didn't cover thoroughly in order to avoid info overload (in retrospect I believe I have failed).

[**HTMLFormElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)

```
const ui = document.forms.ui;
```

[**.nextElementSibling**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31097027/2813224)

```
clicked.nextElementSibling;
```